# subset dataframe by dates stored in list in column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data.frame that has list of dates stored in a column and a date in another. I want to filter the data frame only by dates that month and day  fall within the range's month and day.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(start = seq.Date(today() - 5, today(), 'day'), end = seq.Date(today(), today() + 5, 'day'))
dat1 = dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(range = list(seq.Date(start, end, 'day')))
dat1$date = sample(seq(as.Date('1998/10/01'), as.Date('1998/12/01'), by="day"), 6)
```

and I try to filter by

```
dat1[format(dat1$date, '%m%d') %in% format(dat1$range, '%m%d'), ]
```

but I get an error:

> Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
>     invalid 'trim' argument

Where I was expecting

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

  # A tibble: 6 x 4
  start      end        range      date      
<date>     <date>     <list>     <date>    
1 2018-10-24 2018-10-29 <date [6]> 1998-10-17 ## as pointed out in comments
                                              ## this is incorrect. It would return an empty data.frame.
```

Comment: You may need to use `map` as it is a `list`

Comment: Your coindition is getting `FALSE` for all the rows `mapply(function(x, y) format(x, "%m%d") %in% format(y, "%m%d"), dat1$date, dat1$range)`

Comment: Do you mean 2018, not 1998?

Comment: @camille the year shouldn't matter as the goal is to filter by `%m%d`

Answer (score 0):

You could back into this using lubridate::ymd.  Note, I had to change the range used for sampling date to actually get a true result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1)
data.frame(start = seq.Date(today() - 5, today(), 'day'), 
                 end = seq.Date(today(), today() + 5, 'day')) %>% 
  mutate(date = sample(seq(as.Date('1998/10/15'), as.Date('1998/11/15'), by="day"), 6),
         #using the year from start/end and the month/day from date, is date in the range?
         InRange = ymd(year(start) * 10000 + month(date) * 100 + day(date)) >= start &
                    ymd(year(end) * 10000 + month(date) * 100 + day(date)) <= end) %>% 
  filter(InRange)

   start        end       date      InRange
1 2018-10-25 2018-10-30 1998-10-26    TRUE
```